# What is the cause of bubbles in my lemon tree leaves

Tags: leaves, lemons, discoloration

[image: lemon tree leaves]I have planted a lemon tree in a pot and I have now noticed that some of the leaves have bubbles and the new small ones are reddish in colour. What is the cause of this and what can I do to remedy this?

Thanks